# MySQL Error 1205: Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, locking

I'm using SQLyog to sync a production database to a dev db. On 4 tables, I'm getting:

`Error No. 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Researching the web seems to indicate that a transaction has begun, locked tables, but has not committed. One post said to `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` but the only processes appear to be my own, via SQLyog.

I have also tried a Restart of MySQL, but that didn't help either.

As a relative novice in MySQL, I'm stuck: I can't determine what transaction or process is locking the tables, nor how to clear this situation.

Any suggestions would be gratefully accepted!

MTIA

Comment: Are you importing into Innodb or MyISAM tables ?

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem on MySQL-cluster, I've solved (at least it looks being solved now - no fail have occured during last two days) it by performing commit/rollback after SELECTs too.

Answer (score -2):

Export and re-import your database; this can often fix a lot of mysterious problems. You can do this through phpMyAdmin or from the command line.

This page at MediaTemple has a good set of instructions:
http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/129/Export+and+import+MySQL+databases#gs

(Well, it worked for me!)